# How to align a dynamic button in navigationBarItems

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a custom menu (dynamic based on the editMode) in the trailing part of the navigation bar. I need 3 buttons in "view" mode and only one in "edit" mode.

The problem is I can't align the buttons to the right as below:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the "done" button is way to the left.

I tried adding Spacers() but no luck.

```
.navigationBarItems(
        leading: BackButton(label: "") {
            self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        },
        trailing:
            HStack {
                if self.mode?.wrappedValue == .inactive {
                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                        Button(action: {
                            ////////
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "trash")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                        }
                           ////////
                        Button(action: {

                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                            .imageScale(.large)

                        }

                        CustomEditButton() {
                            ////////
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    HStack {
                        CustomEditButton() {
                            /////
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    )
```

Comment: SwiftUI bug, please submit feedback to Apple.

Comment: did that. I'm curious how long will take from them to get back with an answer

Comment: They usually don't, but there is a chance that it will be fixed in next release(s).

Answer (score 1):

Same issue. Spacer()'s inside or outside of conditional statement don't work.
I noticed is that the alignment is fixed/correct when popping back to the view from a NavigationLink screen, though...
In any case, I made it work on my end using opacities depending on the condition driving the changes.
In your case, a workaround may look like this:

```
.navigationBarItems(
        leading: BackButton(label: "") {
            self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        },
        trailing:
            ZStack {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                    Button(action: {
                        ////////
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                       ////////
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                    }
                    CustomEditButton() {
                        ////////
                    }
                }
                .opacity((self.mode?.wrappedValue == .inactive) ? 1.0 : 0.0)

                HStack {
                    CustomEditButton() {
                        /////
                    }
                }
                .opacity((self.mode?.wrappedValue == .inactive) ? 0.0 : 1.0)
            }
    )
```